# How to whitelist AWS Lambda function for Google API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-api, aws-lambda, google-calendar-api

I'm building an AWS Lambda function that pulls info from the Google Calendar API using Node.js. The Node application then sends an html response to a third party application. I'm basically following [this guide from google](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js), except I'm sending the html somewhere else to be rendered. I keep running into an error where Google tells me I haven't whitelisted the javascript origin coming from Lambda. Here's the error text:

`{error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: ""Not a valid origin for the client: https://<Lambda URL>.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com has not been whitelisted for client ID <My_Google_API_Client_Id>.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."}`

I've gone into the Google API developer console and whitelisted that URL, but I'm still getting that error. [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTEow.png)

I've tried whitelisting "us-west-2.amazonaws.com" as well with no luck. Thanks!!

Comment: *"whitelist this origin"* -- this **exact** origin, `https://x-example.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: That seems to have worked!

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to whitelist Lambda's IP addresses, you can't whitelist based on domain name. You can view the current list of IP addresses here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html

You note your request is coming from `us-west-2` so you could whitelist the IPs from that region only by looking for entries matching that region. 122 by my count so thats a pretty big job!

Otherwise, you could look at setting up a NAT within a VPC and using a IP against that to whitelist that sole IP?

Comment: VPC with NAT gateway is going to be the correct solution here.

Comment: @JorgRoper I believe your answer is off-track.  **Origin** does not mean IP address.  `Origin` is an HTTP request header, similar to `Referer`, that communicates the origin (protocol + hostname) of the page that is making a (typically) cross-origin request. I'm reasonably confident that Lambda isn't making this request.  The browser is making this request.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, but I think I may have accidentally not given all the necessary information. Lambda sends an html response to another application and the request comes when the html is rendered on that page. So it sounds like I have to whitelist the IP for the third party application, but if that were the case why would it show the lambda url in the error? I've updated the original question to add this new info.

Answer (score 0):

White list AWS Lambda functions' subnet NAT gateway elastic IP address. Follow the [article](https://dev.to/kiunakoncepts/white-list-aws-lambda-functions-2k0o).